# Does Facebook Allow App Developers To See a Log of the API Calls It's Received?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

While in development mode, it would be very useful to see a log of API calls from Facebook's perspective. Error messages like this one, would then be intelligible:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "Dt33dWtIpZr"
   }
}
```

Note this does not say what URL Facebook is complaining about.  While it is true that the client side can log this information, it is also true that client-side libraries may be messing things up and not provide a way of logging what they're sending.

Comment: there is no facebook side logging you have access to. that error is very well known though, you can find a lot of stackoverflow threads about it.

Comment: Thanks.  As for the error, I did look at the other answers but, as it turns out, at least in my case, the error report was misworded.  The domain was fine.  What I had overlooked was setting up the the URL -- the entire URL -- as a Valid OAuth Redirect URIs under https://developers.facebook.com/apps/my-app-id/fb-login/settings/